# Could not connect to the database in sqldeveloper, gives error as login failed vendor code 4002

Tags: database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

Could not connect to the database in sqldeveloper, where as 2 other databases are connected. While connecting the database give an error of "Login failed, Vendor code 4002".

Comment: Question flagged as low quality since it lacks even the basic information.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: Not able to connect to only one database while I am already connected to other databases on the same machine...as I mentioned it returns the erroras login failed vendor code 4002. Could you help me with this?

Comment: When was the last time you could successfully connect? What were the recent changes? That error is not an Oracle standard error. So you need to provide more information to make it more specific, as of now your question is too vague.

Comment: I tried connecting the database after and before too since I suspected something wrong in the connection, as it turns out it is able to connect to rest of them only this database is not logging. I have checked with others too who are using the same database if there is anything wrong with it, It is working fine. I tried with the credential which are actually working on the database already and I have done no changes as such also tried with creating all new connection but nothing is actually working.

Answer (score 0):

The above error arises at the time of locking of the account. When an user logs in to the database and exceeds the possible number of attempts to be made, because of access constraints the database may lock the user account and disable for a while until the user requests for unlocking of the account.

It is clear, that the user cannot login to the database in such a situation and gets this error when one tries to.

Thanks